# Running an exe file in windows container using docker

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-for-windows, docker-container

I want to run an exe file on window container using Docker. My exe accepts parameters. New file gets created in predefined directory

```
ie:- Test.exe -f1=file1.txt -f2=file2.txt

**Output** :
Writing file file1.txt
Successfully created file file1.txt 
Writing file2 file2.txt
Successfully created file file2.txt
Enjoy!!
```

My docker file looks like below

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:3.5-windowsservercore-10.0.14393.1715 
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
Copy Test.exe ./TestFolder/
WORKDIR /TestFolder
ENTRYPOINT ["Test.exe"]
CMD ["f1=file1.txt","f2=file2.txt"]
```

I build the image and run the container

```
docker build -t image1 .
docker run -it image1
```

Once the container runs I get the exact above output but when I login to container machine using scripts, I don't see any file created in the predefined path.
Am I missing out anything ? Is this the correct way to run exe file on windows base image?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you login to the container?

Comment: Thrrough script with imagename >> docker run -it --entrypoint powershell imagename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out that the exe was running fine and file was created.
The way I logged into the container was wrong.

I should have used:

```
docker exec -it containername powershell
```

This runs a new instance of a non-existing image

```
docker run -it --entrypoint powershell imagename
```